# Error specializing base class's static method in a subclass

Tags: typescript, inheritance, static

Here's a simplified example of what I'm doing:

```
enum Type {A, B}

class Base<T extends Type> {
  constructor(public type: T) {}

  static create<T extends Type>(type: T): Base<T> {
    return new Base(type);
  }
}

class A extends Base<Type.A> {
  static override create(): A {
    return super.create(Type.A);
  }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Class static side 'typeof A' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Base'.
  The types returned by 'create(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'Base<T>'.
      Type 'Type.A' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        'Type.A' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Type'. ts(2417)
```

Why is this? I don't understand how "`'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Type'`" when I've explicitly extended from `Base<Type.A>`. How do I work around this to create specializations of my base class?

Answer (score -1):

We have a few issues here:

1. You use **value**, not **type** in the child class.

`javascript class Base<T extends Type>`  means you have to provide T which extends Type. But you provide a value `javascript class A extends Base<Type.A>`

In **Generics** you can only provide **type**, not **value/instance**. Examples:

```js
class Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}

class AnimalInfo<T extends Animal> {}

const catInfo = new AnimalInfo<Cat>(); //valid - we provide type

const catInstane = new Cat();
const anotherCatInfo = new AnimalInfo<catInstane>(); // not valid
```

A valid, although not very useful example would be:

```js
enum Type {
  A,
  B,
}

enum AnotherType {
  C,
}

type CombinedEnum = Type & AnotherType;

class Base<T extends Type> {
  constructor(public type: T) {}

  static create<T extends Type>(type: T): Base<T> {
    return new Base(type);
  }
}

class A extends Base<CombinedEnum> {
}
```

2. **Static methods** cannot be **overridden**. Only **instance** methods can be **overridden**

`javascript static override create() ...` is not a valid construction.

3. **super** has no meaning in a static method. **super** applies to an **instance**, not a **static class** implementation.

```js
  static method(): Something {
    return super.method();
  }
```

a valid construction would be:

```js
class BaseClassType {
  static method(): Something {
   //...
  }
}

class AnotherClass {
  static method(): Something {
    return BaseClassType.method();
  }
}
```

Comment: Most of what you said is not true in TypeScript, for example you can use values as generics just fine: `class C<T> { constructor(public t: T) {} }`, `const c = new C(5)`, now I can't do `c.t = 3` because types `3` and `5` are incompatible.

Comment: You said most - and provided one example. I spend my time to describe in 3 points what is not ok. 

In your example you are doing  const c = new C(5), but that is at runtime. In this case T is implicitly identified, BUT in your question you want do declare a class:

Comment: And yes - `c.t = 3` will work

Here is the playground
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCA8AVAfNA3tYB7AdhALgE4Cuw+WhAFAA7EBGIAlsNPgFzSICU6AvtLwCwAKBHY8+TNAC80HAFMA7nEoBWLgG4RYgHSTZAZi2jh4iFhDydILAHNKwPZpFA

Farewell, I hope you get support and get your answers.